# ogr2ogr list all table error

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, command-line

I don't understand the problem when I use this command :

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" "/.../..../.../.../.../gabarits gpkg/aep.gpkg" PG:"host='localhost' user='...' password='...' dbname='...' schemas='..._principale,..._commun,..._aep' LIST_ALL_TABLES=yes"
ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
missing "=" after "LIST_ALL_" in connection info string
```

No syntax mistake, no problem if I retire LIST_ALL_TABLES=YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LIST_ALL_TABLES part does not belong to the PostgreSQL connection string.
Remove that and use one of the two documented options, either the dataset open option or the configuration option https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" "/.../..../.../.../.../gabarits gpkg/aep.gpkg" PG:"host='localhost' user='...' password='...' dbname='...' schemas='..._principale,..._commun,..._aep'" -oo LIST_ALL_TABLES=yes

$ ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" "/.../..../.../.../.../gabarits gpkg/aep.gpkg" PG:"host='localhost' user='...' password='...' dbname='...' schemas='..._principale,..._commun,..._aep'" --config PG_LIST_ALL_TABLES YES
```

Comment: first line generate : Warning 1: -doo ignored when creating the output datasource.
second works fine !

Comment: Sorry, I did not test the commands and I was remembering that `-doo` stands for "dataset open option". Actually it means "destination open option" and thus it would affect the GeoPackage output, not the PG input. Use `-oo LIST_ALL_TABLES=yes` instead. I have edited the answer accordingly.